# Where do i put the config file for flake8 on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, flake8

I installed flake8 to do some work from home on my windows machine, but don't know where to put my configuration file.

The documentation states, that the `flake8` file has to be put in `~/.config/flake8`.

I tried `%USERPROFILE%/.config/flake8` and simply `%USERPROFILE%/flake8` both to no avail. Perhaps, anyone with experience with working with flake8 on Windows can answer this?

Answer (score 2):

If you open up the source code for flake8 (main.py), you will see that on Windows, the default config path is significantly different than it is on Linux:

```
if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
    DEFAULT_CONFIG = os.path.expanduser(r'~\.flake8')
```

On my Windows 7 machine, that resolves to: `C:\Users\username\.flake8`

So you'll have to create a file called `.flake8`. Be sure it begins with a period. I did that by opening up the command line and going to my home folder and executing the following command:

```
NUL > .flake8
```

That created the blank file as you can't create it in Explorer (or I couldn't anyway). Once that's created, you can open it and add whatever you like to it.

**UPDATE** - I finally found some "documentation" that mentions Windows here:

- https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/3.3.0/user/configuration.html#configuring-flake8